# Editing /etc/hosts using WSL vs. using Notepad as an administrator

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hosts

Why am I not able to modify my `/etc/hosts` file in Ubuntu through WSL? But if I try to run Notepad as an administrator and name the file as `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, I am able to modify the `/etc/host` file.

Is this the limitation of WSL, since I am running it in my Windows machine?

Comment: What is the EXACT command you used to try and modify the hosts file? Moving a file from Ubuntu to Windows will strip off the Ubuntu file permissions as Windows does not use or support them.

Comment: You do realize that `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` is the Windows hosts file - this itself has nothing to do with Ubuntu or WSL. But WSL uses this file to map onto the `/etc/hosts` file in Ubuntu, as AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I wouldn't call it a "limitation" of WSL personally -- Really more of an intentional feature.  If you examine `/etc/hosts` in Ubuntu, you should see that the first few lines are:

> `# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:`
> `# [network]`
> `# generateHosts = false`

Yes, WSL autogenerates this file during its `/init` process.  It combines three different sources into the auto-generated file (at least in the latest WSL release):

- The "normal" Linux `/etc/hosts` entries such as:

  - A `localhost` entry for `127.0.0.1`
  - A hostname based entry on `127.0.1.1` (is often inserted by the installer in a typical Linux system, at least [Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution)).
  - Entries for typical useful IPv6 networks
- The Windows host file, since its assumed that you would like to have access to those same hostnames whether in PowerShell, Ubuntu, CMD, etc.

As noted, you can easily disable this auto-generation and have full control over your own file if you'd like.  Just:

```
sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
```

<sub>Side-note: Use `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` to set the default editor used by `sudo -e`</sub>

And add:

```
[network]
generateHosts = false
```

Then exit Ubuntu.

From PowerShell:

```
wsl -l -v
# Confirm the distribution name is "Ubuntu" and adjust the following command if needed
wsl --terminate Ubuntu
```

After restarting Ubuntu, you'll still the auto-generated file (since it was there when you terminated), but if you edit it now, the changes will stick.